# Least squares method to get the fit formula

Tags: statistics, least-squares

This is my first post here. For one of my projects I need to do a temperature compensation according to the distance, browsing I found an article called "High precision infrared temperature measurement system based on dsitance compensation" that does exactly what I need. I have tried to replicate with their data the methodology they propose but I am unable to obtain the same result.

According to the article, a relationship is made between the distance and an adjustment parameter called Y (equation 1 in the image), my problem is not how to solve the ecucations presented in order to obtain the parameters $a_0, a_1, a_2$ shown in equation 4.

Article capture

[image: article capture]

Data

[image: data]

Thank you very much to whoever can help me.

Comment: Chen, Jing & Wang, Ji-Ping & Shen, Tian-Yu & Xiong, Daxi & Liquan, Guo. (2017). High Precision Infrared Temperature Measurement System Based on Distance Compensation. ITM Web of Conferences. 12. 03021. 10.1051/itmconf/20171203021.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct : there is a problem somewhere.

If we use the data
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 d & T \\
 0 & 33.37 \\
 10 & 33.11 \\
 20 & 32.87 \\
 30 & 32.70 \\
 40 & 32.32 \\
 50 & 31.82 \\
 60 & 31.32
\end{array}
\right)$$ and the model is either

$$\frac T {T_0}=b_0+b_1\,d +b_2\,d^2$$  the exact results are
$$b_0=\frac{34988}{34965}\approx 1.0006578$$
$$b_1=-\frac{43}{116550}\approx -0.00036894037$$
$$b_2=-\frac{73}{6993000}\approx -0.000010439010$$ which differ from the numbers they give.

If, as it seems, they fit
$$\frac {T_0}T=c_0+c_1\,d +c_2\,d^2$$  the exact results are
$$c_0=\frac{11681771821960765499}{11687496483739052592}\approx 0.99951019$$
$$c_1=\frac{50500159478371189}{155833286449854034560}\approx 0.00032406529$$
$$c_2=\frac{2449273119119}{201708529727558400}\approx 0.000012142635$$ which also differ from the numbers they give.

Comment: Thank you very much, with your answer I was able to solve my problem